# assemply-changing the characters of my string

Tags: assembly, qtspim

So I want to change all the characters on my string with a single character.I have done this:

```
    .text
    .globl __start
__start:

    la $t2,str# t2 points to the string
    la $a0,str
    li $a1,256
    li $v0,4
    syscall

    la $a0,endl # system call to print
    li $v0,4 # out a newline
    syscall

    li $t4,'-'
    li $t1,0 # t1 holds the count
    nextCh: lb $t0,($t2) # get a byte from string
    beqz $t0,strEnd # zero means end of string
    sw $t4,($t2)
    add $t1,$t1,1 # increment count
    add $t2,1 # move pointer one character
    j nextCh # go round the loop again

    strEnd:
    move $a0,$t1 # system call to print
    li $v0,1 # out the length worked out
    syscall

    la $a0,endl # system call to print
    li $v0,4 # out a newline
    syscall
    li $v0,10
    syscall # au revoir...

.data
str: .asciiz "abcdefghij"
endl: .asciiz "\n"
```

Which just gives me the string I have stored in the data section and a loop which pretty much gets every character of the string.What should I add to my code so I could get this:

```
abcdefghij
----------
```

Comment: Make `str1` as long as `str` and print it, too.  Or use `li $t4, '-'` an loop over your string again using `sw` to store that ASCII character over the old value.  (You don't need `str1` as a single-char string in memory at all).

Comment: study in debugger the memory view, find out how the string is stored in memory (it's ASCII encoded, each character occupies one byte). So to modify the original string in `.data` area of memory, you need to overwrite 10 bytes with value `'-'` (45 in ASCII). But if you are creating "hangman" game, you usually want to have more arrays, one with original string, one with boolean hidden/shown, and do the hide/show logic per letter in the printing function (not damaging the original string by actually overwriting the letters in it).

Comment: @PeterCordes I edited my code but I get the wrong result cause it only gives me one - instead of ---------

Comment: @PeterCordes fixed it you need sb to do that.

Comment: Oh right, sorry, of course you need a byte store not a word store.  Brain fart. 
 (You could `li` a 4-byte constant and store 4 bytes at once...  but then you have to worry about alignment and the string not being a multiple of 4.)

Answer (score 0):

right answer is this:

```
    .text
    .globl __start
__start:

    la $t2,str# t2 points to the string
    la $a0,str
    li $a1,256
    li $v0,4
    syscall

    la $a0,endl # system call to print
    li $v0,4 # out a newline
    syscall


    li $t1,0 # t1 holds the count
    nextCh: lb $t0,($t2) # get a byte from string
    beqz $t0,strEnd # zero means end of string
    li $t4,'-'
    sb $t4,($t2)
    add $t1,$t1,1 # increment count
    add $t2,1 # move pointer one character
    j nextCh # go round the loop again

    strEnd:
    la $a0,str
    li $v0,4
    syscall 

    la $a0,endl # system call to print
    li $v0,4 # out a newline
    syscall
    li $v0,10
    syscall # au revoir...

.data
str: .asciiz "abcdefghij"
ans: .asciiz "Length is "
endl: .asciiz "\n"
```

Comment: food for thought: - why do you count number of chars in the loop, if you don't use it? - why do you initialize `t2` string pointer long before the loop, while you don't use that value elsewhere (like `move $a0,$t2` before first output). Usually in programming try to keep things as local as possible. - why do you reinitialize `t4` inside the loop? - why `$a1=256` at beginning? ... otherwise it does reasonably well what you asked for, i.e. rewrites the original string in memory with minus character.

Comment: (btw, if you are in control of string content, you could have added newline to end of string, and use that as terminator for the "minus" write loop, but then you would need only single `syscall` to output string+newline. But that depends how the task is given, if having newline as part of string makes sense, and actually you would require it by such change.)